# how to display timezone in php

Tags: php, function, if-statement, timezone

I want to display 7 different time for 7 different countries, but as you can see on my code I have just a simple knowledge of programming. My question is, is there a better way of displaying the time for this 7 countries(Sydney,Brisbane,Perth,Bangkok,London,New York, and L.A.) and can I use more than one different date_default_timezone_set in one php file? because on what I tried it only follows one timezone. Appreciate all the help, thanks.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <title>PA Toolbox</title>
<?php
function a(){
if(date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney'))
    {
    date("format");
    echo date( 'h:ia');
    }
}

function b(){
    if(date_default_timezone_get('Australia/Brisbane'))
    {
     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp); 
     echo date( 'h:ia');
   }    
}
//else
//elseif(date_default_timezone_get('Australia/Perth'))    
//    {
//     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp);
//    }
//elseif(date_default_timezone_get('Asia/Bangkok'))    
//    {
//     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp);
//    }
//elseif(date_default_timezone_get('Europe/London'))    
//    {
//     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp);
//    }
//elseif(date_default_timezone_get('America/New_York'))    
//    {
//     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp);
//    }
//elseif(date_default_timezone_get('America/Los_Angeles'))    
//    {
//     $date = date(“format”, $timestamp);
//    }    
?>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>    
    <td>Sydney and Melbourne</td><td>Brisbane</td><td>Manila and Perth</td> <td>Bangkok</td><td>London</td><td>New York</td><td>Los Angeles and San Francisco</td>  
    </tr>
    </>
    <td><?php return a(); ?></td><td><?php return b(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date( 'h:ia'); ?></td><td><?php echo date( 'h:ia'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date( 'h:ia'); ?></td><td><?php echo date( 'h:ia'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date( 'h:ia'); ?></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>
</html>
```

The clock works fine, but how do I design it so that the numbers move without refreshing the page?

Comment: Just discovered this while researching your question, not sure if it will help: http://fi1.php.net/strftime Otherwise see @deceze answer for using `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/DateTime), you don't need to change your default timezone every time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('YourOwn/LocalTimezone'); // fill in the blank

$timezones = array(
    'Sydney'    => 'Australia/Sydney',
    'Melbourne' => 'Australia/Melbourne',
    ...
);

foreach ($timezones as $name => $timezone) {
    $localTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    echo "$name: ", $localTime->format('h:ia');
}
```

Comment: @sir deceze Sir how can I make the numbers move without refreshing the page

Comment: Then you need to do the whole thing in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

see this Url

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php

**And Try**

**This will print the time zone for country CA (Canada), region QC (Quebec).**

```
<?php
$timezone = geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region('CA', 'QC');
if ($timezone) {
    echo 'Time zone for CA/QC is: ' . $timezone;
}
?>
```

Comment: you can set country and region in array and put value in above the code with for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use given function for timezone

```
            $datetime=new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
            $time=new DateTimeZone(timezone);//timezone
            $datetime->setTimeZone($time);//setting timezone
            $datetime->format($format);//convert date and time format
```